# page not refreshing as expected

Tags: services

currently i'm trying to consume drupal service from phonegap and php file.I'm using drupal 7x with services 3.5.Right now login and logout works,but after logout,the page doesn't refresh as it should be.And it gives me this on firefox console :

[image: ask]

return get with ?_=

Here are my codes :

[code] http://pastebin.com/M3FbsgBt

When i refresh the page,the get dissapears,does such behaviour is normal?How can i make it works as expected?Thanks.